# Como não incluir o finally e ainda sim fechar IO Streams, Connections, Statements, e outros Recursos?

Tags: java, arquivo, try-catch, try-finally, io

Sabemos da necessidade de fechar recursos (arquivos, conexões, também chamados de *resources*) consumidos em Java, tais como `OutputStream` e `InputStream`. Quando não os fechamos, criamos problemas de performance e impedimos o Garbage Collector de liberar memória e finalizar o Objeto, entre outros problemas como *memory leaks*.

**Idioma *try-catch-finally***

Abaixo temos o principal idioma que contempla o cenário mencionado acima:

Este código abre um arquivo, lê suas linhas, printa cada uma, captura exceção, caso ocorra, e finalmente em caso de sucesso ou erro, fecha o recurso, ou seja o arquivo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No código acima o compilador não nos obriga a adicionar o bloco `finally`, que é importante para fechar o `BufferedReader` e todos os outros objetos de IO associados a ele, tendo ocorrido ou não exceções e erros. Sem o `finally` nosso código pode perfeitamente compilar, rodar em ambientes de teste, e só revelar a falha em producão.

**Como não precisar incluir o `finally` e ainda sim fechar `Connection`s, `Statement`s, `ResultSet`s, `Reader`s, `Writer`s e até mesmo objetos nossos que necessitem de um método de fechamento - `close()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Devemos utilizar o idioma *try-with-resources***

Também conhecido como *try-with-resourses statement*, este artifício está disponível a partir da versão 1.7 da plataforma Java SE.

**Como?**

No *try-with-resources*, podemos escrever código que se utilize de *resources* para aplicação, tais como `Connection`s e arquivos. *Desde que* tais classes implementem a interface **`AutoCloseable`**.

Através do uso de objetos que implementem `AutoCloseable`, é possível se aplicar um novo idioma, onde não é necessário mais do bloco `finally`. O compilador infere o bloco, garantindo que os recursos sejam fechados. Esta interface tem um único método - `close()`, onde nele, o programador fornece a lógica de fechamento.

A boa notícia é: a partir do Java 1.7, classes como `Reader`, `Writer`, `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet` e muitas outras já implementam esta interface.

**Então como fica o código?**

O código escrito, pode ser reescrito da seguinte maneira:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"))) {
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**E se o programdor acicionar o `finally` mesmo assim?**

Sem problemas, o que é escrito no `finally` é unificado com a chamada para o `close()` que é inferida pelo compilador, assim sendo, se chamar o `close()` em seu `finally`, o mesmo será executado duas vezes.

> **Como não precisar incluir o `finally` e ainda sim fechar os `Connection`s, `Statement`s, `ResultSet`s, `Reader`s, `Writer`s e até mesmo
>   objetos nossos que necessitem de um método de fechamento -
>   `close()`?**

Como vimos, usando o idioma *try-with-resources*, é possível se atingir este objetivo, já no caso de nossas classes se aproveitarem disso, basta fazer com que implementem a interface **`AutoCloseable`**.

Nota: Também existe a interface `Closeable`, que é subinterface da `AutoCloseable`. Porém em seu método `close`, uma `IOException` está em sua assinatura:

```
public void close() throws IOException;
```