# Trecho de código em Try

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

Estava fazendo correções numa classe e me deparei com o seguinte código, não sabia que isso era possível e nunca parei para pensar, mas por que isto é válido? Me refiro a **primeira linha** do Try. Para mim *try/catch* sempre foi no formato:

```
try{
...
}catch(Exception e){
...
}
```

O seguinte código é a mesma coisa que escrever na "sintaxe" acima?

```
try (FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(templateFile)) {
                Workbook wb = write(validation, WorkbookFactory.create(fs), planilha);
                File file = relatorioPlanilhaDAO.exportSheet(planilha.getNomeHash());
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                if (wb != null) {
                    wb.write(fout);
                } else {
                    Log.error(this, "Erro ao escrever no arquivo.");
                    throw new InternalServerErrorException("Erro ao exportar relatório.");
                }
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();

                return file;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.info(this, "Erro ao obter planilha.", e);
                throw new NotFoundException("Erro ao exportar planilha.", e);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.error(this, "Formato de planilha inválido.", e);
                throw new InternalServerErrorException("Formato de planilha inválido.", e);
            }
```

Comment: veja esta questao @DanielaMarquesdeMora
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71638/como-n%C3%A3o-incluir-o-finally-e-ainda-sim-fechar-io-streams-connections-statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é a mesma coisa.

O segundo se trata de um [`try` with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), introduzido no Java 7, que resumidamente é um `try` que declara um objeto [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), no seu caso um [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html). Isso quer dizer que havendo falha ou não, a `FileInputStream` será fechada automaticamente.

Seria semelhante se o primeiro código fosse assim:

```
try{
  ...
  FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(templateFile);
}catch(Exception e){
  ...
}
finally {
  fs.close();
}
```

Você mesma pode criar seu objeto `AutoCloseable`, bastando implementar esta classe ou a [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

Um bom artigo em português para entender melhor pode ser visto aqui: http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2011/10/o-novo-try-no-java-7-por-uma-linguagem.html